# Investigate complex integral on the circle

Tags: complex-analysis

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb4yZ.jpg

Compute

$$
\int_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{z^2-1}
$$
For positive sense of the circle.

We simplfy below as $(z-1)(z+1)$. After that, we modify $\frac{1/(z+1)}{(z-1)}$ to make as Cauchy-Integral

Comment: There are two singularities inside $|z|=2$. Either start with a partial fractions decomposition or split the curve into two pieces, each enclosing just one of the singularities. (Once you know residues, there are quicker approaches.)

Comment: could you please tell me more about singularities !

Comment: the singularites are poles at $z= 1$ and $z=-1$. given that you don't know the residue theorem, use the partial fraction decomposition to get $\frac{2}{(z-1)(z+1)} = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1}$ and use the Cauchy integral formula on $\int_{|z|=2} \frac{dz}{z-a}$

Comment: and note that with the parametrization $\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}, t\in [0,2\pi]$ and the change of variable $z = \gamma(t), dz = \gamma'(t) dt = 2 i e^{it} dt$ you get $$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{dz}{z-a} = \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{2 i e^{it} dt}{2 e^{it} -a}$$
and note how the result of a contour integral doesn't depend on the parametrization we chose